# Ajax url parameter in joomla module

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, joomla, module

Joomla module having a main file, xml file, ajax.php file, css folder, js folder and tmpl folder with default.php file.

default.php file has jquery ajax function. The url parameter is calling ajax.php file. This file is ecohing true or false(ie; joomla code - email has been sent or not).

```
jQuery.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url : 'modules/mod_abc/ajax.php',
            data : {
                varName : zxi,
                varEmail : zxj,
                varPhone : zxk,
                varTime : zxl
            },
            dataType : 'text',
                            .............
                            ..............
                            ...............
});
```

This output is not getting in default.php file. If i remove defined (JEXE) line iam getting the value from ajax.php file.

I want ajax.php file as part of joomla module with defined (JEXE) line also. In it i want to write joomla's mail function

Help me please...

Answer (score 1):

The module files are called within the joomla, that is why the 'JEXEC' param is needed, to determine wheter the refferer is joomla itself. This means, that you canno insert this code into your ajax.php file, since you are calling it with ajax and not including it with joomla.

The solution would be to create a component for your module as a "helper". The url in your ajax call would be pointing at the component, since you can call them from anywhere and you can check JEXE paramether as well.

```
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://yoursite.com/index.php?option=com_abc',
        data : {
            varName : zxi,
            varEmail : zxj,
            varPhone : zxk,
            varTime : zxl
        },
        dataType : 'text',
```

This method would pass the parameters to your com_abc component and you can do in the component whatever you want. If you are planning to use the return values, then use the format=raw parameter as well, to let joomla know not to print out the whole page for the ajax call:

```
  type : 'POST',
    url : 'http://yoursite.com/index.php?option=com_abc&format=raw',
    data : {
        varName : zxi,
        varEmail : zxj,
        varPhone : zxk,
        varTime : zxl
    },
    dataType : 'text',
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  jQuery(window).load(function(){
   var data = {};
   display_result_data();
  });
function display_map_result_data() {
var ajaxUrl = "modules/mod_mapcontent/submit_form.php";
 jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: ajaxUrl,
              data: {category: 'simple'},
              dataType    : "json",
              async       : false,
              success : function(result){
                data = result;
               }
          });
}
 </script>
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_banners
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
*/
  defined('_JEXEC') or die;
  $baseurl = JURI::base();
?>
 <div id="mapcontent" class="mapcontent">
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 </div>
```